# Can't sudo ruby gems binaries on Ubuntu 11

Tags: sudo, ubuntu-11.04

I am ruby1.8 user, as well as `gem`; it's library manager system.

`gem` is able to install binaries, like `rails` and `bundle`.

But I could not get access for this guys until I added this line to my `.bashrc` :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

So now, the binaries work, but not if I use `sudo` first!

```
fabianops ~/workspace3/peded $ sudo rails s thin -p80 -blocalhost --debugger
[sudo] password for fabianops: 
sudo: rails: command not found
```

I need sudo to bind port 80, how can I use `sudo rails ..` ?

Never had that issue with Ubuntu 10.

**update:**
I guess, what I want is for these PATH to be available system wide.

Answer (score 1):

By default `sudo` resets environment to minimal set of variables. See 'SECURITY NOTES' section in `man sudo`.  To preserve you environment variables you could use `sudo -E` (or see `env_reset` option in `man sudo`). Also, to debug, you could try comparing output of `sudo env`/`env` and `sudo gem env`/`gem env`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `sudo su -`
2. `rails s thin -p80 -blocalhost --debugger`

Determine the actual error.  Or explicitly pass the path to rails so the sudo cmd.

Comment: Did that, and got: `The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: ... `

Comment: Does `whereis rails` while elevated locate things?  How did you install rails?  Basically it seems like your path isn't right.  Rather than pollute the root account and/or other accounts, it's probably better to use the explicit path to rails when you run sudo.  YMMV.